# Need help condensing sql server query using local variables. Also need hints for accounting for leap year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, local-variables

I recently switched jobs and therefore also switched from oracle to sql server. I'm attempting to write a stored procedure that will generate a report on demand. The report will show monthly amounts and the sum of these amounts. I am mostly having trouble with the summing part of this. The full query is at the very bottom of this post.
 As you will see from my super-long query, I've basically written it twice to get the sum amount in the Total_Current_Plus_Archived column. I was thinking of using a local variable for this (@totalReportSum). I wanted to update this variable each time a total column is calculated but get errors no matter what syntax I use. Here are a couple of the things I've tried:

Attempt 1.

```
--March total   
                     (SELECT @totalReportSum  =@totalReportSum + Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-03-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-03-31' )) 
                     AS March_Total_Reports,
```

Attempt 2.

```
--March total   
                 @totalReportSum = (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-03-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-03-31' )) 
                     AS March_Total_Reports,
```

If possible, I would also like suggestions as to how I can account for leap years.

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_get_ram_report @year NCHAR(4) 
AS 
BEGIN--declare variable to hold total sum of reports 
  DECLARE @totalReportSum INT; 

  --initialize sum 
  SET @totalReportSum = 0; 
END 

SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT r.ramid 
                     AS Ram_ID, 
                     r.ram_fname 
                     AS RAM_First_Name, 
                     r.ram_lname 
                     AS RAM_Last_Name, 
                     Count(*) 
                     AS Number_of_Agencies, 
                     Isnull(Sum(m.yearly_avg_reports), 0) 
                     AS Yearly_Avg#_of_reports, 
                     Round(Isnull(Sum(m.yearly_avg_reports), 0) / 12, 2) 
                     AS Monthly_Reports_Expected, 
                     --January 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-01-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-01-31' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS January, 
                     --January total   
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-01-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-01-31' )) 
                     AS January_Total_Reports, 
                     --February 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-02-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-02-28' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS February, 
                     --February total   
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-02-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-02-28' )) 
                     AS February_Total_Reports, 
                     --March 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-03-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-03-31' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS March, 
                     --March total   
                 (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-03-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-03-31' )) 
                     AS March_Total_Reports, 
                     --April 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-04-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-04-30' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS April, 
                     --April total   
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-04-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-04-30' )) 
                     AS April_Total_Reports, 
                     --May 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-05-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-05-31' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS May, 
                     --May total   
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-05-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-05-31' )) 
                     AS May_Total_Reports, 
                     --June 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-06-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-06-30' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS June, 
                     --June total   
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-06-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-06-30' )) 
                     AS June_Total_Reports, 
                     --July 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-07-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-07-31' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS July, 
                     --July total   
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-07-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-07-31' )) 
                     AS July_Total_Reports, 
                     --august 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-08-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-08-31' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS August, 
                     --august total   
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-08-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-08-31' )), 
                     --september 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-09-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-09-30' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS September, 
                     --September Total 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-09-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-09-30' )) 
                     AS September_Total_Reports, 
                     --October 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-10-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-10-31' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS October, 
                     --october total 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-10-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-10-31' )) 
                     AS October_Total_Reports, 
                     --november 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-11-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-11-30' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS November, 
                     --november total 
                     (SELECT Count(*) 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-11-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-11-30' )) 
                     AS November_Total_Reports, 
                     --December 
                     (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-12-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-12-31' ) 
                             AND ( ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 ) 
                     ) AS December, 
                     --December Total 
                     (SELECT Count(*) 
                      FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                     ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                      WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-12-01' ) 
                             AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-12-31' )) 
                     AS December_Total_Reports, 
      --Total Current +archived: Would like to replace this huge chunk w/ something a lot smaller 
                     ( (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                        FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                               INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                       ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                        WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                               AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-01-01' ) 
                               AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-01-31' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-02-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-02-28' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-03-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-03-31' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-04-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-04-30' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-05-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-05-31' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-06-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-06-30' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-07-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-07-31' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-08-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-08-31' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-09-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-09-30' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-10-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-10-31' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-11-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-11-30' )) 
                       + (SELECT Count(*) 
                          FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
                                         ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
                          WHERE  ( mx.ram = m.ram ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date >= @year + '-12-01' ) 
                                 AND ( ai.crash_date <= @year + '-12-31' )) 
                     ) AS 
                     Total_Current_Plus_Archived 
FROM   dbo.municipality AS m 
   INNER JOIN dbo.ram AS r 
           ON m.ram = r.ramid 
GROUP  BY m.ram, 
      r.ramid, 
      r.ram_fname, 
      r.ram_lname 
ORDER  BY ram_last_name
```

Comment: if ai.crash_date is a datetime column, you can use the following:  AND(MONTH(AI.CRASH_DATE)='FEB') to account for the whole month of FEB (or any other month for that matter) regardless of start or end date. My only other suggestion for the time being is to dump the local variable concept for the time being and concentrate on getting the query exactly right.  You may also want to look at pivoting the months so the rows become columns so you don't need to do 12 sub queries in the from clause.

Comment: Would you be amenable to putting a sample schema on SQL Fiddle for us to play with? Would be really nice to have a sample of what you're working with to query against. Looks like there are only 3 table too.

Comment: @TexasTubbs: thank you for that suggestion, that will definitely take care of the leap year issue. I just had to modify your sql to the following: AND(MONTH(AI.CRASH_DATE)=2) since keeping it as-is gave the following error when calling the stored proc: "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Sp_get_ram_report, Line 13
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'FEB' to data type int.". I'll also play around w/ pivoting per your suggestion and see if that yields something I can use.

Comment: @Jeremy Pridemore: I uploaded the three tables schemas being used to SQL Fiddle as you asked.
This is my first time using SQL Fiddle so please let me know if I uploaded what you
had in mind. I tried uploading the stored proc but it's over the 8000 char limit.
Here's the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dc0d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, I would like query this way. Then, you don't need care about leap years

```
;WITH monthly AS
(
    SELECT 
        mx.ram 
        ,DATEPART(month,crash_date) AS report_month
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN ai.insert_datetime - ai.crash_date < 35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Expr1
        ,Count(*) AS Expr1_total
    FROM   dbo.accident_information AS ai 
    INNER JOIN dbo.municipality AS mx 
        ON mx.agency_ori = ai.agency_ori 
    WHERE DATEPART(year,crash_date) = @year             
    GROUP BY mx.ram,DATEPART(month,crash_date)
)                 
SELECT
    r.ramid AS Ram_ID, 
    r.ram_fname AS RAM_First_Name,
    ...
    ,(SELECT Expr1 FROM monthly mt WHERE mt.ram = m.ram AND report_month = 1) AS January
    ,(SELECT Expr1_total FROM monthly mt WHERE mt.ram = m.ram AND report_month = 1) AS  January_Total_Reports
    ,(SELECT Expr1 FROM monthly mt WHERE  mt.ram = m.ram AND report_month = 2) AS February
    ,(SELECT Expr1_total FROM monthly mt WHERE mt.ram = m.ram AND report_month = 2) AS  February_Total_Reports
    ...
    ,(SELECT SUM(Expr1_total) FROM monthly mt WHERE mt.ram = m.ram) AS Total_Current_Plus_Archived 
FROM   dbo.municipality AS m 
INNER JOIN dbo.ram AS r 
    ON m.ram = r.ramid         
GROUP  BY m.ram, 
      r.ramid, 
      r.ram_fname, 
      r.ram_lname 
ORDER  BY ram_last_name
```

Comment: EricZ: Your answer looks like a potentially good solution. I'm a little confused on the very 
first line though: ";WITH monthly AS". Does the stored proc create statement go 
before this? I tried the following and got the error below: 

CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_get_ram_report @year NCHAR(4) 
with monthly
AS 
  BEGIN...rest declaration 
  
  Error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Sp_get_ram_report, Line 5
'monthly' is not a recognized option.

Comment: @Bruno,  ;WITH is part of SELECT, you need put it after BEGIN, before SELECT. please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for the assist. I got this to work very nicely with the query you provided. I lacked knowledge of the WITH statement and it turned out to be exactly what I needed. The only thing I changed was to add isnull statements around the select statements like so: ,isnull((SELECT Expr1 FROM monthly mt WHERE mt.ram = m.ram AND report_month = 1),0) AS January. I tried to add  isnull around the selects in the WITH statement like this:  isnull(Count(*),0) AS Expr1_total but would still get nulls. Thanks again!